Implementing OAuth Authentication with GitHub for Teams Bot/Message Extension App
I am developing a Teams bot/message extension application using the Teams Toolkit within Visual Studio Code and TypeScript. As part of the functionality, I am aiming to integrate user authentication with GitHub utilizing the OAuth protocol.
I have reviewed the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-oauth-provider) available on implementing OAuth authentication for Teams tab apps; however, I understand this approach may not be directly applicable to bot/message extensions.
I would greatly appreciate guidance on the appropriate approach to implement OAuth authentication with GitHub for my Teams bot/message extension app. This would allow the app to leverage functionalities offered by the GitHub API on behalf of authenticated users.
Thank you for your time and assistance.

This document is also helpful to your scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample.
In the meanwhile, the Teams-AI library lets you easily add authentication to your bot/message extension. Here's the doc you can refer: https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/blob/main/getting-started/CONCEPTS/USER-AUTH.md. As long as you created an OAuth Connection by following the first doc, you should be able to use it in the Teams-AI library.
